# Symfony2 Create a dynamic header and footer and include in base

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a base.html.twig like this:

```
...
<body>
{% block body %}
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>                            
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

And this works fine. But I need to include a Header and footer that always  been charged in my application. Before and After the content. But these two blocks aren't statics, soy I need to pass attributes, querys result...

I haven't idea how do this, because if I include another block I need to create a route in route.yml and I will need call this routing every time. How usually people do this in Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `include` simple header & footer, or `render` the controller creating it if you need more than just "static" content:

```
<body>
{% block body %}
    {% render(controller("AcmeBundle:header")) %}
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    {% include footer.html.twig %}                            
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Comment: I need more than static content, but in this case I need a new path in the routing.yml and an user can enter directly in this path. This will be perfect if exist any way to restrict this. Thanks!

Comment: @symfnoyuser you don't have to create a route for the action you want to render. In my example, there is no route defined for headerAction.